# Logic App to Azure DevOps REST API with Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

Is it possible to authenticate Logic App calls to DevOps REST API using Managed Identity?
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops) shows only SDK possibilities, but no logic app examples provided.

I tried Azure DevOps connector, but it uses your personal credentials and creates API connection.
[oAuth2.0 flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token) is also a bit overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution. Quite simple after hours of searching.

Just put the Azure DevOps Application ID as an audience [as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb9yB.png)

You can take it from Azure AD, but it's the same for all - [499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFkry.png)